# Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 with domain user without network connection

Tags: 14.04, login, domain-server, nis

I'm not an advanced Ubuntu user so please be patient with me.

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, signed my computer to a Windows domain (using nis) and was able to login with my domain user.
I've also added my user to the sudoers group.

Now I have two issues:

1. When my computer is not in the network, I can't login with my domain user
2. Every time I reboot Ubuntu, I need to type my username again (this is a minor issue)

I've searched for a solution all over the place but was unable to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't login as a domain user, when network is not available. Because it pulls the user information from the domain server.

Comment: Ok. Is there a workaround? My computer won't be connected to the domain all the time (it's a laptop).

Comment: If you can create a local user on the laptop, then create a local user and login with the local user all the time. When you want to be in your domain, you can always do ' su - <domain user name> ' and be that user and continue your work

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, it may be related to the network problem. I doubt it can show a domain user on the login prompt, because it is not possible to know which user will login. If you create a local user, then it will appear on the login prompt.

If not please check the output of " /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf " If you see something like this, 
greeter-show-manual-login=true. Just comment that line or make it as greeter-show-manual-login=false. Next time you reboot, you will not be asked for login id.

Comment: I've specifically set this option so that I will be able to login with my domain user. I thought that my first login, the username will be stored in the operating system and will be shown next time I try to login.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure about that. BTW, what setting you will do to store the domain user name?

Comment: I have no idea. That's why I'm asking this question. Currently I need to enter the domain username every time (in Windows, I can see my domain username in the logon screen).